# Strange event propagation on Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-propagation

I've spent about an hour around this problem and can't figure it out.
Here it is:

I created component in Vue called `<CheckboxList/>` that renders checkboxes given props `itemName`, `items` and `milestone`. The last one is optional, and I just use it for an specific case.

I'm using [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/).

Here is the component:

```
<template>
<v-card class="grey lighten-4">
    <v-container class="mt-0">
        <template v-if="milestone">
            <v-chip class="mb-4" color="indigo" text-color="white">
                <v-avatar left>
                    <v-icon>flag</v-icon>
                </v-avatar>{{ milestone.name }}
            </v-chip>
        </template>
        <v-text-field class="py-0" :label="`Filter ${itemName}...`" v-model="filterItem"></v-text-field>
        <v-row id="checkboxListBox">
            <v-col
                xl="3"
                lg="4"
                md="6"
                sm="12"
                v-for="item in getFilteredItems"
                :key="`${itemName}_${item.id}`"
                class="py-0"
            >
                <v-checkbox
                    v-model="selectedItems"
                    @click.capture="!milestone ? $emit('checkbox-changed', selectedItems) : $emit('checkbox-submilestone-changed', { milestoneId: milestone.id, selectedItems })"
                    :label="item.name"
                    :value="item.id"
                />
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</v-card>
```

The component works well when I don't use cycles to render it:

```
<CheckboxList
    itemName="milestones"
    :items="getMilestones"
    @checkbox-changed="selectedMilestones = $event"
/>
```

It does the job of storing all selected milestones in the right variable. The event propagation works well.

The problem comes when I render it using `v-for`. I want to render as many components as selected milestones, and it does it well. The problem is it doesn't store the state correctly!

I'll show you what happens:

No clicks made yet - 
[selectedSubmilestones object empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60byt.png) as it should be.

1st click made - [selectedSubmilestones object still empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGd6.png) when it shouldn't be. But the console logged the events correctly.

2nd click made - [selectedSubmilestones object is filled when it shouldn't be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAKfI.png). The console still logged the events correctly (empty array because there are no selections).

And it stays like this, filling the object incorrectly when it shouldn't.

I really can't understand, here is the `handleSubmilestoneCheckboxClick()` function:

```
handleSubmilestoneCheckboxClick(e) {
    console.log(e)
    const { milestoneId, selectedItems } = e
    this.selectedSubmilestones[milestoneId] = selectedItems
}
```

Here it is the v-for rendering:

```
<template v-for="(milestone, index) in getSelectedMilestonesWithSubmilestones">
    <CheckboxList
        :class="index !== selectedMilestones.length - 1 ? 'mb-4' : ''"
        v-if="getMilestoneById(milestone).submilestones.length"
        :key="'submilestone_checkboxlist_' + milestone"
        itemName="submilestones"
        :items="getMilestoneById(milestone).submilestones"
        v-on:checkbox-submilestone-changed="handleSubmilestoneCheckboxClick($event)"
        :milestone="getMilestoneById(milestone)"
    />
</template>
```

Please help :)

Comment: First of all don't add `v-for` for `template`, see what happen and let me know.

Comment: @Syed I did what you suggested and nothing changed.